# Node.js 3 functions synchronous, then wait for all functions execution and result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I need to call 3 functions, which must work synchronously. When all functions will finish execution, then I need to execute `console.log` for example.

Schematic example:

```
function one() {
    console.log('one');
}

function two() {
    console.log('two');
}

function three() {
    console.log('three');
}

one();
two();
three();

if ( ... function one, two and three were completed ... ) {
    console.log('Success!');
}
```

The main condition is that the functions performed synchronously. Maybe it is possible to do with `async` library?

Comment: Those functions are all synchronous so your question doesn't really make sense as the `if` won't be reached until they all complete.

Comment: It was just an example how they will look like. In real script each function will take about 3-20 seconds, but result must be shown only if all functions were finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with [`parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) :

```
async.parallel([one,two,three], function (err, results) {
  console.log('Success!');
});
```

Note that the `one`,`two`, `three` functions must all accept a callback argument, into which they will send their result or failure when completed.

Comment: Thanks, As I have said this was just schematic example! Each function in real life will take about 3-20 seconds. Using them in async way will take 1 minute, but I want to make it faster, but final result must be shown when all functions were finished.